# Apache2 rewrite doesn´t work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am making a test with codeigniter and I make this .htaccess:

```
 #Options +FollowSymLinks
 #Options -Indexes
 DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|Scripts|images|uploads)
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

On the config files of apache where is necessary make many changes, I have this (only what I think is important for this case):

## /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

## /etc/apache2/site-available/000-default.conf

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory />
   #Options FollowSymLinks
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The path where the codeigniter is installed is in /var/www/html/test, and if on browser I make http://ejemplo.com/test the wellcome controller of igniter works, but if I try to access to other function on this controller I get a 404 (make by apache, not the 404 from codeigniter).

Do I forget something?? What am I doing wrong??

Thank you.

PS:The codeigniter is an empty and new installation (only a helloworld function on the wellcome controller).

Comment: ouchhh!! f... after hours looking for the answer, and after try a lot of things... now that I make the question.. I find the solution (I swear I had tried).
On the htaccess I need to put this RewriteBase /wifi
Thank you anyway.

Comment: You should always specify a `RewriteBase` directive if you are using relative path substitutions in the `RewriteRule`. However, it is not obvious from your question that you would need to specify `/wifi` - that seems a bit "random"? If "codeigniter is installed in /var/www/html/test" then it would be reasonable to assume that `RewriteBase /test/` would be required.

Comment: @w3d you are right... I put var/www/html/test on the explanation I don´t know exactly why, but finally is wifi the path. Thanks!!